# how to sum of a column with different values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which contains val_type column which have 3 type of values

```
 id     val_type   company
 1       rib         1
 2       mod         2
 3       rib         2
 4       rib         3
 5       mod         1
 6       trop        1

 $res= SELECT SUM(val_type) from tabl_name GROUP BY company;
 with above query I get sum of all types in one

  Result Required : Rib=3, mod=2 and trop=1
```

I want to get sum of all three types with one MySQL query. like how many rib,mod and trop.

Thanks

Comment: There's no spite there. If the question is 'wibble wobble dribble', the answer isn't 'fibble wibble dibble'. It's 'please clarify your question'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *count* all three types.  You only need a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    val_type,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tabl_name
GROUP BY
    val_type;
```

Comment: You should discard your current query, because it is wrong, and not close to what you need here.